Stop a triggered build in jenkins pipeline
I have a jenkins pipeline that triggers another job at some point, lets call that triggered_job. tiggered_job takes a long time to finish. and depending on some logic in my pipeline I might need to stop that job. How would I do that?
I found out I can perform an http call to stop that build but I would need the Build Number. and if the triggered_job hasn't finished yet, doing a myjob = build 'triggered_job' wouldn't get it.
One more thing to keep in mind is that the triggered_job might run multiple builds so getting the latest isn't a concrete way of getting my build.
This is not a duplicate to Jenkins: get the build number of a Job triggered inside pipeline. Since that assumes the build has finished.

Build numbers are used to identify unique builds so you need to get it somehow. You can get the latest build number immediately after triggering the job and keep it stored in a variable in case you need to stop it later.

+1 to ^^^. also try to add waitForStart parameter to myjob = build job:'triggered_job', waitForStart:true - then check the class/type of the result println myjob.getClass()- then check documentation for this class maybe it will have the build id in properties...

If you are in the same master you can do something like that:
def pipeline = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('full.path.to.your.pipeline')
def build = build wait: false, job: 'full.path.to.your.pipeline', waitForStart: true
def id = build.getId()
//add your logic 
pipeline.getBuild(id).doKill()


N.B. "full.path.to.your.pipeline" is not the https url to the pipeline but the relative path from your master ex. if https url is "https://jenkins/master/job/folder/job/pipeline" the path will be "folder/pipeline"

def build = build wait: false, job: 'full.path.to.your.pipeline', waitForStart: true

With this snippet you can start n builds and the pipeline don't wait untill it's finished, just wait the downstream job to start.
